# 301 Redirect every page on a site to a new domains homepage

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I know there a million other posts like this but this ones a bit specific.

Basically I have an old site that has been dead, just made it live again and theres still a few old links in Google. I want to do something in the htaccess that will 302 redirect ALL pages and the site to my new domain. for example I need:

www.oldsite.com > www.newsite.co.uk

oldsite.com > www.newsite.co.uk

www.oldsite.com/?color=red > www.newsite.co.uk

www.oldsite.com/?color=red&size=large > www.newsite.co.uk

www.oldsite.com/page > www.newsite.co.uk

www.oldsite.com/something.html > www.newsite.co.uk

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that a .htaccess file is the answer.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* http://www.newsite.co.uk/? [R=301,L]
```

As you want to redirect everything, no `RewriteCond` required.
Believe you'll want it 301'ed though if you want Google to follow these

Edit: Have added ? to the end of the domain to redirect to. This will remove the current query string.

Comment: ah yes sorry the 302 was a typo. was meant to say 301. :)